# Gradle 8.0 subprojects failed to apply plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle that contains the following:

```
    ...
    subprojects {
        apply plugin: 'java-library'
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Trying to upgrade to gradle 8.0 and running into the following error:

> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin'.
> No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.JvmPluginsHelper.configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact() is applicable for argument types: (String, null, String, EmptyList, String, org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet_Decorated...) values: [sourcesElements, null, sources, [], sourceJar, main source, ...]

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact` in the [upgrade notes for Gradle 8](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#jvmpluginshelper) finds this note.

> ##### JvmPluginsHelper
>
> A deprecated `configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact` method of the `JvmPluginsHelper` class which did not require a `FileResolver` has been removed. This was an internal API, but may have been accessed by plugins. Supply a `FileResolver` to the overloaded version of this method instead.

If your build scripts uses `configureDocumentationVariantWithArtifact` then you can use the overloaded version.

Otherwise, it's possible that you have applied a plugin that is uses this now-removed method. Run with `--stacktrace` and look in the output to try and determine the plugin.